# Javax mail api: getting message.getdescription()= null

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I read mails through imap, and I was able to get messages, their subject, sent date, and from address. But the message description is `null`. I used Javax mail api 1.4.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Now is the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In a nutshell: **What is your question?** Is description supposed to be not null? What should it be?

Comment: message.getDescription() was supposed to give me body of the mail. which im getting null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MimeMesage [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getDescription()), getDescription() method is used to get the "Content-Description" header field of the message.

If you want to extract the body, you can use the MimeMessageParser on the message object.

```
final MimeMessageParser parser = new MimeMessageParser(message);
String body = null;
try {
    parser.parse();
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Exception during parsing the message body: {}", e);
}
if (parser.hasPlainContent()) {
    body = parser.getPlainContent();
} else if (parser.hasHtmlContent()) {
    body = parser.getHtmlContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getDescription--) for `MimeMessage::getDescription()` says:

> Returns the "Content-Description" header field of this Message. This typically associates some descriptive information with this part. **Returns null if this field is unavailable or its value is absent.**

So, if `getDescription()` is returning `null`, that means that the MIME message you are trying to read doesn't have that field, or the field is empty.

It is legitimate for the "Content-Description" to be missing, since [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-27) states:

> This header field is always optional.

---

In short, your application should be designed cope with `getDescription()` returning `null`.

---

You commented:

> message.getDescription() was supposed to give me body of the mail. which im getting null.

That is not what `getDescription()` does.  If you want the **body** of the mail, use `getContent()` or `getContentAsStream()`